# How is Kahlúa made?

Tags: liquor

Kahlúa is coffee rum. It's delicious, but is it just regular rum mixed with coffee, or is there more to it than that? Is coffee added before distillation? Is the coffee somehow fermented?

Answer (score 8):

From [Kahlua's website](http://www.kahlua.com/bean-to-bottle/) it looks like they process sugar cane into molasses, ferment it, and distil it before adding coffee. The coffee, vanilla, and caramel is added eight weeks before the mixture is filtered and bottled.

[Wiki How has a few recipes](http://www.wikihow.com/Make-Kahlua) for home made "kahlua", but I have my doubts.